# What does@Component do in angular2

Tags: angular

i am new to angular 2. I understand the import statement means we include the component class in this file.

My question is who has an explanation why we need @Component annotation what exactly does it do?

```
import {component} from '@angular2/core';

@component
{

}


export class MyComponent
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It adds metadata to the class MyComponent It actually makes the class a component
without it the class would be a normal typescript class

---

Further information here: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/03/the-difference-between-annotations-and-decorators.html

Answer (score 0):

The `@Component` annotation is a [Typescript decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html). Decorators are a special kind of declaration that can be attached to a class declaration, method, accessor, property, or parameter.

Angular's Component annotation applies the needed framework building blocks for it to be a usable component within Angular2. More specifically:

> The `@Component` annotation specifies when a component is instantiated, and which properties and hostListeners it binds to.

See also [Component decorator on Angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can think of @Component as a configuration function that compliments the
class, and that annotation turns your class into an Angular component actually.

Angular internally parse the @Component annotation (and all the annotations) and generates additional code adding requested behavior to the class.

If you look at the transpiled code of your class you can see what Angular does with the @Component annotation, somthing like:

```
MyComponent = (function () {
   function MyComponent() {
      ...
   }
   ...
```